# performSegueWithIdentifier is not presenting the desired View

Tags: ios, swift

I've set up a "show detail" segue from one viewcontroller to another. however when i execute below code nothing happens, it doesnt show the viewController. I'm 100% that the identifier in the segue is identical. What can course this?

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("PresentPermissionView", sender: self)
```

i'm calling it in this method

```
func determinePermission() {

    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {

    case .AuthorizedAlways, .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

        }

    case .NotDetermined:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        print("test")
    case .Restricted, .Denied:

        print("restricted")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("PresentPermissionView", sender: self)

    }
}
```

Comment: What type of segue is this? Modal or push or something else? Are you sure the the line above gets executed? With a bit more details, I would be able to help you more

Comment: modal! yes it is printing "restricted" in the log

Comment: Does it present a different view? or is it not segueing at all? Perhaps add an `override prepareForSegeue` function to test out what may be causing this.

Comment: prepare for segue is being executed, but view isnt presenting

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call this method?

Try to log if it actually prepares to do the segue by overriding:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    print("Preparing for segue using: \(segue)")
    print("With it's destination view controller: \(segue.destinationViewController)")
}

override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

Comment: i've added the method where im calling it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your storyboard might not have the identifier set, that's why it is not calling. To set the identifier, selected your segue and put the copy paste the string you have in the `self.performSegueWithIdentifier` method.

This is how your storyboard configuration should look like:
[image]

If you have all this configured right and the behavior is still not the one you expect, check the logs to see if you have a configuration error.

Hope this helps! Let me know how it goes :)